# awk selective page numbering for print

Tags: awk

I have a string containing page numbers of a .pdf-file I want to print, but I want to minimize the length of the string in order to replace all the consecutive numbers with a dash, in order to do selective printing with awk. Can anybody help me out with a code for awk?

from

> 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53,

into

> 1,3-13,15-51,53

Comment: Are the numbers presented on a single line?  Are they separated by commas?  If there's more than one line of input, should each line be processed separately?  Are the numbers presented in sequence (sorted)?  What do you want as output if the input is `93,96,97,100`?  You could get `93,96-97,100` or `93,96,97,100`.

Comment: Incidentally, `10` is missing from the data; presumably, the expected output is `1,3-9,11-13,15-51,53`.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part of this problem is that you don't know how to print the previous values until you've received the next.

Here's a script that works sensibly when fed multiple lines of input, treating each line as a separate set of numbers to be processed.  It ignores empty fields altogether (leading, adjacent or trailing commas).  It assumes that the fields on each line are all numeric and sorted in ascending order.  It doesn't really work with negative numbers in the data (the formatting using dashes to separate ranges becomes clunky — but the data is correct), but it is happy with zeros.

It is not the most compact code possible, but I believe clarity is more important than compression, especially when getting it right (optimization or compression comes later, if it is necessary).

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }

function print_range()
{
    if (lo == hi)
        printf "%s%d", pad, lo
    else
        printf "%s%d-%d", pad, lo, hi
    pad = ","
}

{
    lo = ""
    hi = ""
    pad = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
        if ($i == "")   # Ignore empty fields - could report them
            continue
        else if (lo == "")
            hi = lo = $i
        else if ($i == hi + 1)
            hi = $i
        else
        {
            # Previous range complete - print it
            print_range()
            lo = hi = $i 
        }
    }
    print_range()
    print ""
}
```

I used a file `script.awk` containing the code above, and invoked `awk -f script.awk data*` to generate the output shown below.

Here is some sample data (based closely on the data from the question):

```
1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53,
1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53
1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51
```

The first line has a trailing comma; the others do not.  The third line and subsequent lines are missing entries 29 and 32, so there is a 2-element range 30-31 present in the data.  The last two lines have a multi-element range at the start instead of a single item; the last line has a multi-element range at the end instead of a single item.

The output from the script is:

```
1,3-9,11-13,15-51,53
1,3-9,11-13,15-51,53
1,3-9,11-13,15-28,30-31,33-51,53
3-9,11-13,15-28,30-31,33-51,53
3-9,11-13,15-28,30-31,33-51
```

It is easy to tweak the printing to detect if `hi == lo + 1` and decide to print comma-separated values instead of dash-separated values if that's preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -e 'BEGIN { ORS = ","; RS = ","; O = -1 } { if(N + 1 == $1) { N += 1;} else { if (O != -1 && O != N) { print O,"-",N } else { print N; } O = $1; N = $1; } }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf "1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53," |
  awk '
  function handleRange () {
     if (previous == 0) {
       first=$0
     } else if (previous != ( $0 - 1 )) {
       if ((previous - first) == 0) {
         print previous
       } else if ((previous - first) == 1) {
         print first ORS previous
       } else {
         print first "-" previous
       }
       first=$0
     }
     previous=$0
  }
   /[0-9]/ { handleRange(); }
   END     { handleRange(); }
  ' RS=, ORS=,
```

Output:

```
1,3-9,11-13,15-51,53,
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very short awk program that will do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     {gsub(/,+/,","); gsub(/^,|,$/,"")}
     {delete a; for(i=2;i<NF;++i) a[i]=($i-$(i-1) == 1 && $(i+1)-$i == 1)} 
     {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (a[i]) $i=""}
     {gsub(/,,+/,"-"); print}' file
```

The following steps are taken:

1. **Cleanup:** remove empty fields

   ```
   {gsub(/,+/,","); gsub(/^,|,$/,"")}
   ```
2. **Make check:** check if the previous field is one less and the next field is one more then the current field. Store this information in a new array.

   ```
   {delete a; for(i=2;i<NF;++i) a[i]=($i-$(i-1) == 1 && $(i+1)-$i == 1)}
   ```
3. **Delete:** if the previous condition is true, delete the value

   ```
   {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (a[i]) $i=""}
   ```
4. **Hyphenate:** multiple commas imply a sequence, replace them with a hyphen.

   ```
   {gsub(/,,+/,"-"); print}
   ```

Step 2 and 3 can actually be combined by using two temporary variables (`a` keeping track of the original value of the previous field, and `b` a true temporary)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     {gsub(/,+/,","); gsub(/^,|,$/,"")}
     {a=$1; for(i=2;i<NF;++i) {b=$i; $i=($i-a == 1 && $(i+1)-$i == 1) ? "" : b; a=b}}
     {gsub(/,,+/,"-"); print}' file
```

Comment: Good work, except perhaps when there is a 2-number range (N and N+1) such as in `93,96,97,100`. Then you output the input instead of `93,96-97,100`.  Granted, this is one of the edge cases not covered by the test data, so it isn't clear which is preferred.  I covered this explicitly in my answer.  Because of the way you're detecting ranges, it would be quite hard to adapt your code to spot 2-element ranges and hyphenate them — but that may not matter.

Comment: I didn't expect the code to be so complex, this one works fine. For printing it does not matter if it is a dash or a comma in between the numbers as long as the string is reduced by so much.

Comment: @sdf feel free to accept and/or upvote any of the answers you like best.